# How to count the number of columns containing a particular string in r?

Tags: r, rstudio, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have some data that has names and tags associated with those names. There are upto 94 tags for each name. Each tag is in a separate column. I need to count the number of columns that contain a particular string. How can I do that?

Edit: Sample data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJtwd.png

I want to count the number of columns that contain the string "WG".

Comment: Could you provide us with a reproducible data?

Comment: Hi @JimO. I added an image of the sample data.

Comment: Very easy:
rowSums(df == "WG")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the number of columns containing "WG" row-wise.

```
apply(X = df,MARGIN = 1,function(t){sum(grepl(pattern = "WG",x = t,fixed = TRUE))})
```

Answer (score 1):

I made-up some data with different situations, abe has apple twice, chris has apple in the third key, ethan has no apples. With this solution, if there is no match the name is dropped.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_df<-data.frame(name=c("abe", "ben", "chris", "doug", "ethan"),
                  key1=c("apple", "apple", "banana", "apple", "orange"),
                  key2=c("apple", NA, "orange", NA, NA),
                  key3=c(NA, NA, "apple", NA, NA),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df %>% gather("key", "tag", -name) %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(tag=="apple") %>% tally()
```

data

```
> my_df
   name   key1   key2  key3
1   abe  apple  apple  <NA>
2   ben  apple   <NA>  <NA>
3 chris banana orange apple
4  doug  apple   <NA>  <NA>
5 ethan orange   <NA>  <NA>
```

output

```
  name      n
1 abe       2
2 ben       1
3 chris     1
4 doug      1
```

For your unique situation you may need to explore how the `gather()` function works and maybe use `select()` to select specific columns. If you are new to tidyverse pipes, I suggest starting with running the first pipe, and inspecting how each phrase modifies the dataframe (ex, `my_df %>% gather("key", "tag", -name)` ).

edit; can simplify using the count function's built in grouping:

```
my_df%>%gather("key", "tag", -name)%>%filter(tag=="apple")%>%count(name)
```